# ubuntu server how to boot to "recovery mode"

Tags: ubuntu

I accidentally removed my user from the sudo group.

A friend of mine told me to go into recovery mode and edit the visudo file.

The problem is, I don't know how to get into recovery mode. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? I am on ubuntu server 10.04 64bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to hold down the SHIFT key during boot and this should present you with the option to boot to recovery mode.

EDIT: (Assuming it is a single and not a dual boot system)

Comment: It is a single boot. Thanks I will try this when I get home :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you're in, you don't edit the visudo *file*; you can either

- use `visudo` (assuming you know how to use `vi`, or do `EDITOR=nano visudo` (or whatever editor)), which safely edits `/etc/sudoers` and does sanity checking before saving
- `addgroup <username> admin`, since the admin group is in the `sudoers` file

Of course, you shouldn't add yourself to the admin group if you weren't in it to start with... which won't be a problem if it's your server...

Comment: Thanks! I was in the admin group I just used usermod -G without -a, and yes the server is mine. It's just a small home server.

Comment: Thanks again! I used the command usermod -a -G sudo <username>